# How to not allow inbound or outbound traffic in AWS VPC default security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I'm trying to disable inbound and outbound traffic from my default security groups, I already did it for my custom-created VPC using the `restrictDefaultSecurityGroup: true` but I'm finding another default VPC security group related to my Default VPC, I tried to access it using the code below but this doesn't seem to access the default security group, any suggestions would be helpful, I'm trying to achieve this using cdk not the AWS cloud Console.

```
this.disableDefaultVpcTrafficSg = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'DisableDefaultVpcTrafficSg', {
  vpc: ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'DefaultVPC', { isDefault: true }),
  allowAllOutbound: false,
});
```

[image: Im trying to fix the security HUB issues]

Comment: The code you've written appears to create a new security group in the default VPC. See [ec2.SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.html) for how to import an existing security group so you can update the rules on the existing, default security group.

Comment: You cannot update rules of an imported SG, though - would adding another rule work? My intuition would be that it wouldn't.